# Export netty generated documentation to Markdown

Tags: markdown

Our application currently uses netty for our API and we are pleased with it however we are trying to export the documentation it generates into Markdown. We have not had any luck finding a direct way to do this. Does anyone have any insight or advice on exporting from netty into Markdown or a format it would accept? Thanks

Comment: Can you add more details? Are you referring to http://netty.io/ (I'm not aware of any documentation generation feature built into that library)? What kind of documentation do you get?

Comment: If it is netty.io, then they provide javadoc.  Searching google for javadoc to markdown produces several results, but I have not had enough experience with any of them to make a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try incorporating the source from https://delight-im.github.io/Javadoc-to-Markdown. It's client side conversion though. It might work in javax.script on server side I suppose.